# Simulate bash "snow fall" script in ncurses/C

Tags: c, linux, bash, ncurses

So I saw this bash script the other day that simulates snow fall on a terminal.  I thought it would be an easy project to learn ncurses in C but I have made a total mess of it.  My approach was just to fill some strings with random snowflakes and write them to the screen.  I am not getting anything I expected.  Basically just a big mess that flies by at the speed of light.

Can anyone put me on the right track?  Here is the script I want to copy behavior of.

```
#!/bin/bash

LINES=$(tput lines)
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)

declare -A snowflakes
declare -A lastflakes

clear

function move_flake() {
    i="$1"

    if [ "${snowflakes[$i]}" = "" ] || [ "${snowflakes[$i]}" = "$LINES" ]; then
snowflakes[$i]=0
    else
if [ "${lastflakes[$i]}" != "" ]; then
printf "\033[%s;%sH \033[0;0H " ${lastflakes[$i]} $i
        fi
fi

printf "\033[%s;%sH*\033[0;0H" ${snowflakes[$i]} $i

    lastflakes[$i]=${snowflakes[$i]}
    snowflakes[$i]=$((${snowflakes[$i]}+1))
}

while :
do
i=$(($RANDOM % $COLUMNS))

    move_flake $i

    for x in "${!lastflakes[@]}"
    do
move_flake "$x"
    done

sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: Please show us your code, what your expected output is, what the output you're actually getting is, and ask a specific question about a problem you're having.

Comment: The code was edited and commented out so much that it was just a mess and erased it out of frustration before posting here.  This was not homework just an attempt to alleviate boredom gone terribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can live without the line at the bottom of the screen that pretends to be snow accumulating on the ground it is pretty simple.  The main trick is to scroll down the screen not up.  However if you do want that bottom line it gets harder and you may need to try an approach other than this one.

I only just tested this on my machine so as in all things curses the usual caveats about your terminal's milage varying apply.  In any case, something for you to chew on and play with.  Cntl-C should kill it but putting in some proper error handling would be a good exercise too.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    initscr();

    int  maxRows, maxCols;

    getmaxyx(stdscr, maxRows, maxCols);

    int flakesPerRow = maxCols * 0.02;

    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);

    while (true)
    {
        //setup top line
        for (int i = 0; i < flakesPerRow; ++i)
        {
            int x = rand() % maxCols;
            mvaddch(0, x, '*');
        }

        move(0,0);  //keeps cursor from bouncing around
        scrl(-1);   //scroll down, not up
        refresh();
        napms(200); //delay 200ms
    }

    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Or maybe it is up and not down the screen.  One of these days I'll get it straight.

Comment: Thanks!  This is infinitely better than what I was doing and I see many things I was doing wrong.